# jqPlot tick mismatch using dateAxisRenderer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, graph, jqplot

For the life of me I cannot figure out the problem behind ticks being off on my x-axis using dateAxisRenderer. This only occurs in ranges more than 1 month. I am manually setting a min and a max and all my date data comes in the format `Y-m-d` from php. I tried everything I could find to force the ticks at the beginning and end of the graph and avoid the mismatch half way through the graph. I've attached a screenshot demonstrating the problem. I also appended a fix to the daysInMonths array (wrong numbers) in dateAxisRenderer, but the variable seems not to be used anywhere.

**NOTE:** The data shown in the js is just to demonstrate structure, a real set is too to post.

Picture:

[image]

In the above picture, at the change of the month, the mismatch occurs. The label at 29th October has the point and data for the 30th. Running `console.log(targetPlot.axes.xaxis.max)` always returns the js epoch for my max + 1 day, even though my max is explicitly set.

My code:

```
var graphData = {"object1":[["2013-01-01", 0], ["2013-01-02", 0]], "object2":[["2013-01-01", 0], ["2013-01-02", 0]]};
var time = '%#d-%b-%y';
var min = '2013-10-23';
var max = '2013-11-21';
var toPlot = [graphData.object1, graphData.object2];
$.jqplot.enablePlugins = true;
window.targetPlot = $.jqplot('chart-main', toPlot, {
animate: true,
animateReplot: true,
seriesDefaults: {
    showMarker: false,
    pointLabels: { show: false },
    markerOptions: {
        show: true,
        style: 'filledCircle',
       size: 7
    }
},
seriesColors: colours,
cursor: {
    show: true,
    showTooltip: false
},
series: [
    {
        showMarker: true,
        lineWidth: 2,
        rendererOptions: {
            animation: {
                speed: 1500
            }
        }
    },
{
        showMarker: true,
    lineWidth: 2,
    yaxis: 'y2axis',
    rendererOptions: {
        animation: {
            speed: 1750
        }
    }
}               
],
axesDefaults: {
    useSeriesColor: true,
    rendererOptions: {
        alignTicks: true,
        tickDistribution: 'even'
    }
},
axes: {
    xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
    tickOptions: {
        angle: -65,
        fontSize: '8pt',
    formatString: time
        },
    min: min,
        max: max
    },
    yaxis: {
    tickOptions: {
        fontSize: '8pt'
    },
    min: 0,
    pad: 0
},
    y2axis: {
        tickOptions: {
            fontSize: '8pt'
        },
        min: 0,
        pad: 0
    }
}
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying parts, there is a bug that occurs on some data sets spanning more than 1 month and auto-generating the ticks for these months. The number of days in each month are wrong and used incorrectly throughout the dateAxisRenderer. The bug has been reported (in a different fashion) previously by another.

To avoid having to remember to update my dateAxisRenderer next time I update the file I now define my ticks (the fall back) and do not include the dateAxisRenderer.